# What live OS with reasonably small size that I can use to rescue files on a laptop?

Tags: ubuntu, rescue

I only have two flash drives: 4GB and 1GB.

I would like to create a bootable flash drive for a live Lubuntu installation, so that in case my very old laptop's Lubuntu can't boot, I can rescue my files by booting into the live Lubuntu out of my flash drive.

Since lubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso is 1GB, my 1GB flash drive (with actual size a little smaller) will probably not be able to hold it.

I am not sure if it is a common practice to dedicate a whole flash drive to a live OS, but [I think it is a waste to use the entire 4GB flash drive for live Lubuntu.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/445443/how-can-i-create-a-bootable-flash-drive-for-lbuntu-and-also-store-temporarily-ot)

So I was wondering if there is an alternative to lubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso for my 1GB flash drive? How can I use the alternative to boot into my laptop, and to retrieve my files there? I haven't tried other Linux distributions other than Ubuntu, so I am scared of trying those minimalist Linux distributions without GUI, but I am a little familiar with `cp` and `rsync` which I can use to copy the files out.

Thanks.

Comment: Ubuntu minimal/netboot should fit your needs: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/18.04/ It could also be used to repair your installation, since it uses the same repositories as Lubuntu.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering how to put the netboot into my 1GB flash drive and make it a live OS. Shall I first download http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/mini.iso, and then run `dd if=/path/to/mini.iso of=/dev/sdb  bs=4M && sync`, assuming my flash drive is `/dev/sdb`? `mini.iso` is less than 100MB, so shall I dedicate my 1GB flash drive to it?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Will the live OS out of mini.iso work for me to retrieve files, if I don't have access to the internet? @Mioriin

Comment: 1GB is a LOT for a rescue system. You can have rescue disks with 200MB

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro do you recommend something else around 200MB other than `mini.iso`? I agree there will be a lot of waste space in my 1GB flash drive for `mini.iso`.

Comment: A 4 Gb flash drive is ~5 $ nowadays, so "waste" is a bit of an exaggeration.

Comment: @Tim drikt answer seems fine. Often you can have custom recover partitions builds in an extra recovery partition if you do not want to deal with USB/DVDs, but that has to be planned.

Comment: I use a setup close to this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/435057/how-can-i-install-several-linux-distributions-on-a-usb-stick/435371#435371). The super GRUB iso will allow you to boot to linux and Windows, and the PartedMagic ios contains a 32bit and 64bit GUI with clonezilla too. I use this a lot in my everyday job.

Answer (score 3):

For rescue work, I can recommend [SystemRescueCD](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org). Also comes in a [USB version](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/Installing-SystemRescueCd-on-a-USB-stick/)

It has everything you need to repair a damaged system from the command line.

Of course, no one stops you from rolling your own, if you like.

Comment: Thanks.  SystemRescueCD is 32-bit OS. Will it work to rescue files on ext4 under 64-bit Lubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Yes: The filesystem looks the same, no matter if the kernel is 32-bit or 64-bit. Having different filesystems for 32-bit and 64-bit Linux variants would be a major PITA, and lots of people would have complained...

Comment: Thanks. I create a bootable flash drive by `sudo dd bs=4M if=systemrescuecd-x86-5.2.2.iso of=/dev/sdb conv=fdatasync`, but when I reboot and select the flash drive to boot into, it doesn't boot into the SystemRescueCD in the flash drive, but the Lubuntu on my hard drive. So I was wondering if I miss something? (note that previously, I ran similar `dd` command to create a live Lubuntu OS on a flash drive, and I could boot into the live Lubuntu on the flash drive in the same way)